# Build and run grpc-java examples without gradle

Tags: java, grpc

I'm trying to make examples from grpc-java work.
It's indeed easy if I'm using gradle, however, I'm going to integrate grpc into the project that uses another build system.
I would like to know how to compile and run examples using only protoc, javac and java.
I'm able to generate java sources from .proto sources, but no luck compiling the generated java sources.

I tried 1000 combinations (different classpathes), but nothing works.

```
> javac RouteGuideGrpc.java

< RouteGuideGrpc.java:3: error: package io.grpc.stub does not exist
import static io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.asyncUnaryCall;
```

(99 other compile errors were omitted)

Could anyone show a sequence of commands that will work?
Thank you.

Upd: I'm doing this on Linux.

Upd: I'm using SBT, but it really does not matter. What I really want to understand is how to use javac to compile generated grpc code.
I'm sure I have grpc-core, grpc-netty, grpc-protobuf and grpc-stub in classpath (actually, not sure in anything at this point...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I was able to resolve compile-time issues.

I ended up inserting println statements into the build.gradle files that come with grpc to see the actual class-path that is used when compiling those examples.

It turned out that grpc libs had versions 0.9.0, while in my sbt build I was referring to 0.7.2.

Just today libs of version 0.8.0 were put to the maven repository and when I change the version from 0.7.2 to 0.8.0 everything works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I actually faced a couple of problems myself trying to migrate from Gradle to SBT.

First you should take advantage of [sbt-protobuf](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-protobuf) plugin which compiles `.proto` files for you. Make sure to:

- Set the *path* and *version* of your `protoc`:

```
version in PB.protobufConfig := "3.0.0"
protoc in PB.protobufConfig := PATH_PROTOC
```

- If needed set the location of your `.proto` files (default is `src/main/protobuf`):

```
sourceDirectory in PB.protobufConfig := baseDirectory.value / "src" / "main" / "proto"
```

- Finally, set extra options of `protoc` used by `grpc-java`. First options sets the path for your `protoc-gen-grpc-java` plugin bin; and second sets the output path of grpc-java to the same as `sbt-protobuf`:

```
protocOptions in PB.protobufConfig ++= Seq(
    "--plugin=protoc-gen-grpc-java=" + PATH_GRPC_JAVA_PLUGIN,
    "--grpc-java_out=" + baseDirectory.value + "/target/src_managed/main/compiled_protobuf")
```

I ended up putting a repository with all of this sorted out. [Here it is](https://github.com/jfloff/grpc-java-sbt), hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

The package `io.grpc.stub` is part of the grpc-stub artifact. To build the code generated component, you need at least `protobuf-java`, `grpc-stub`, `grpc-protobuf`, and `grpc-core` in your classpath. Depending on how you are compiling, you may also need any protobuf generated classes (the grpc-generated stubs depends on the protobuf-generated protos).

There is documentation for running the code generator manually in the [compiler directory](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/compiler/README.md), but it doesn't include running `javac`.

If you continue having problems, double-check that the protoc compiler and protobuf-java have the same version, and protoc-gen-grpc-java and the grpc JARs have the same version.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I looked at the docs and I'm able to generate java code for messages and services from .proto files.
The problem comes when I'm trying to compile generated java files.

Comment: @Timmy, I mentioned many other things than the docs. Are those various libraries on your classpath, and have you double-checked that the protoc version matches protobuf-java and the protoc-gen-grpc-java version matches the grpc JARs?

Comment: Eric, you were right in that I need `grpc-*` libs in my classpath.
However, version 0.7.2 (that was available at that time in maven central repository) of those libraries was obsolete.
As I described in answer, I ended up just checking what is the classpath for compiling the examples - and versions were higher than 0.7.2.
I manually extracted those libraries from gradle cache and it worked.

On August 14th, many grpc libraries of version 0.8.0 were uploaded to Maven http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cgrpc - so I don't have to use local maven repo.